# GNURadio Companion and gr-ax.25 or gr-packetradio

Tags: packet-analyzer, gnuradio

As you've seen many times before "I'm new to Linux". Add me to the list of newbs.

So. I need to send a variety of APRS (Automatic Packet Reporting System) packets from an emulated transmitter. I'm using GNURadio Companion and a HackRF One.

I can't install gr-ax.25 nor gr-packetradio on anything.
https://github.com/m0mik/gr-packetradio

I've tried Pybombs. I can get Pybombs installed on one installation of Ubuntu. I can reach the ./app_store.py on one installation (pc) running Ubuntu. I can't get it to run on Ubuntu in a virtualbox though.
http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/pybombs/wiki

So While attempting to install gr-packetradio from Pybombs the build basically stalls.

I can't get Pybombs to work on Manjaro (Well, a friend of mine who writes code for a living in Manjaro couldn't get it to work), I looked over his shoulder in dismay.

Basically I'd like to use the code/block from m0mik, but basically I have no idea how to install it from those instructions. Its far too vague for a neophyte.

I'm at the point where I can install GNURadio on most of the Linux machines I've tried. The frustrating thing is that doe all the permutations (VirtualMachanies and or real installs) all the error codes are different and meaningless when trying to install the packetradio add-on.

What I'm trying to accomplish is fairly strait forward at this point. I need to at least recieve APRS packets (that use the AX.25 protocol) inside GNURadio. To do this I was hoping to install the well known software GNURadio Companion, and the pre-written/built software package for it (gr-packetradio) to do this.

I've got a dedicated computer to do this and I'm willing to format the machine and start over to get it to work. What I need is detailed instructions that will actually get me to that goal.

Can anyone out there give a guy a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could boot into this live distro. http://www.shackbox.net/ I haven't used it myself but I hear it works just fine.

If you have a dedicated machine and do a fresh install you're not able to follow the pybomb directions? If you can install gnuradio via the pybombs you'll then be able to "./pybombs install gr-packetradio"